# Why is "anchor build" and "Cargo build-bpf" showing wrong rustc version?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, solana, bpf, anchor-solana

I'm trying to build the (https://github.com/betterclever/solend-anchor) package using `anchor build`, however I get the following error

```
error: package `uint v0.9.3` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.56.1 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.56.0-dev
```

I updated rustc and running the command `rustup default nightly`shows:

```
info: using existing install for 'nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin'
info: default toolchain set to 'nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin'

  nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin unchanged - rustc 1.61.0-nightly
```

So it shows me that the installed and active rustc version is 1.61, however anchor build is not finding that for some reason. I also tried running cargo build-bpf but the same thing kept happening. `cargo build`seemed to work fine.
I'm wondering what is causing the problem when running anchor build and cargo build-bpf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`anchor build` and `cargo build-bpf` use a different compiler than the normal `rustc` compiler included in the system, so it's normal that they report a different version.  The BPF compiler comes with the Solana tool suite.

If you already have the Solana tools installed on your computer, you can simply run:

```
solana-install init 1.9.13
```

And if you don't, you can run:

```
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.9.13/install)"
```

That will give you all of the newest tools, including the BPF compiler.

Answer (score 3):

I have Solana latest version, I faced the same error while compiling one of the downloaded program.
Command

```
solana-install update
```

Worked for me.