# Rust version problem when running cargo build-bpf

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustup

I am trying to run `cargo build-bpf` on a basic start rust program.

I installed Rust with the curl command `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`.

When I run `cargo --version` I get `cargo 1.75.0 (1d8b05cdd 2023-11-20)`.
When I run `rustc --version` I get `rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)`.

But in my project directory, when I run `cargo build-bpf` I get an error saying:

```
error: package `package` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.72.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev
```

How is it using version `1.68.0-dev`? I tried running `rustup update` but I still get the `1.68.0-dev` error?

Comment: Maybe you have a `rust-toolchain.toml` in the current directory? Check this for overrides: https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html

Comment: Or check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71598808/why-is-anchor-build-and-cargo-build-bpf-showing-wrong-rustc-version?rq=2 run `solana-install update ` if you are running within the Solana ecosystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran `solana-install update` and it said "Install is up to date".

Ran `cargo build-bpf` again and got error:

```
error: package `solana-program v1.18.1` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.72.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.72.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.1 --precise ver
where `ver` is the latest version of `solana-program` supporting rustc 1.68.0-dev
```

To fix it I ran the following: `solana-install init 1.18.1` and then when I ran `cargo build-bpf` again it worked.